# set culture information for custom date format

Tags: asp.net, datetime, date-format, cultureinfo

I am facing a problem in date format. I am converting a string date(dd/MM/yyyy) to datetime, using convert.toDateTime(). It works fine on my local machine but causes problem when I run from server. So to set uniformality, I tried to set culture info for (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) format, but couldn't set as .net shows an error.

I tried like this.

```
CultureInfo DateInfo = new CultureInfo("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

How can I set the culture info for this format?

Comment: what is the problem while running from server..? can u provide a more info....?

Comment: See this message.. SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use like this...

```
string dateString = "Mon 16 Jun 8:30 AM 2008"; // Modified from MSDN
            string format = "ddd dd MMM h:mm tt yyyy";
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Response.Write(dateTime);
```

hope this may helpful...

Comment: Hi Chirag Fanse... check your parameter string or compare to my dateString value to yours variable value is equal or not.. May be the Am and Pm getting changed i think try to solve the issue.

Comment: If your parameter values is equal to my variable values then it will be work(First two lines dateString and Format).The third line is giving error right..? check your parameter...

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work     Since it seems you have not yet discovered how to accept answers

Comment: My date is 27/12/2011(dd/MM/yyyy) for 27th dec-2011. How can I do for this type of date..??

Comment: Do some string manipulation and try to change your string like this.. `string dateString = "Mon 16 Jun 8:30 AM 2008";` `string format = "ddd dd MMM h:mm tt yyyy";`  Its also DD/MM/YYYY format. check it out.